# how to create relation between table A and C

Tags: php, yii

I have 3 tables named A,B and C.

```
Table A: id,
         B_id

Table B: id,
         C_id

Table C: id,
         *column
```

a have a very little knowledge about creating relations like this:

```
'tableB' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'B', 'B_id'),
```

how can i create a relationship in table A so that I can access the `*column` in table C? I'm using yii. Thanks!

Comment: What database engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through
You should be able to define a relation from A to C through B.

```
'tableB' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'B', 'B_id'),
'tableA' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'C', array('C_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'tableB'),
```

Comment: it throws errror: Property "CBelongsToRelation.through" is not defined.

Comment: "CBelongsToRelation.through" property (available since v1.1.7)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure while, but logical way described in the accepted answers gives me:
`Property "CBelongsToRelation.through" is not defined.`

Easy workaround that worked for me is to switch `BELONGS_TO` with `HAS_ONE` in the second relation:

```
'tableB' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'B', 'B_id'),
'tableA' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'C', array('C_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'tableB'),
```